# Upgrading from SharePoint Foundation 2013 to SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise

Tags: migration, sharepoint, licensing

TechNet has an article for this that start with point 1 and ends on point 2. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16033.sharepoint-2013-migrate-from-sharepoint-foundation-2013-to-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

This is not very explanatory. There are other articles too that talk about only for upgrading from SharePoint Foundation 2010 to SharePoint 2013 but none of them talk about SharePoint Foundation 2013 to SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise.

We have currently Foundation 2013 installed on our server.

Also I can see in Central Administration there is 'Convert Farm license type option' under Upgrade and Migration.

So just by providing the license key is it possible to upgrade from Foundation 2013? or we need to follow the steps from TechNet article?

Which one if true and How we can achieve the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In-place upgrade of SharePoint 2013 Foundation to Full is not supported, the only supported upgrade type in this case is Database-attach upgrade. which the link you provided already mention (building a new environment and moving the database to it)

Review supported editions and products for upgrading to SharePoint 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747.aspx

Upgrade content databases to SharePoint 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx

Comment: Suppose I have installed SharePoint Foundation 2013. I have key of SharePoint Server 2013. By going to Central Administration, if I apply the key then will it upgrade to SharePoint Server 2013?

Comment: That option is usually used to change SharePoint from running in trial mode to licensed mode. or upgrade from Standard mode to Enterprise mode, but it's not supported on the Foundation edition.

Comment: I'm wondering that why they even give an option to Convert Farm license type in SharePoint Foundation 2013 then??

Comment: @kamalpreet SharePoint is full of inconsistencies, and even a few features that you can see that just are not completed (company profiles come to mind).  it's just the nature of the product.  Foundation does not include all the "bits" you need which is why just putting in a key won't work.